# Is CSS going to be disconnected after detach & appendTo in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, detach

Below code is non working code and that does not matter one bit for the purpose of this question. Question below code!

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="popup1"></div>
  </div>
</body
```

CSS

```
.wrapper #popup {
  color: #fff;
}
```

jQuery

```
var setpopupoutsidewrapper = $('#popup1');
setpopupoutsidewrapper.detach();
setpopup1outsidewrapper.appendTo('body');
```

**Is the link between the CSS/HTML going to stay intact after the detach/append function?**

Comment: No it wont, because the rule no longer applies since it is outside of the `.wrapper` div. If your css was just `#popup { ... }` instead of `.wrapper #popup { ... }` the style would stick around.

Comment: The current CSS selector will no longer apply once `popup1` is a child of the body. `.wrapper #popup` says there is a descendant with id `popup1` somewhere below an element with the class `wrapper`. Once `popup1` is a direct child of body that will no longer be true.

Comment: @The Maniac thank you very much for that information. That is exactly what I needed to know. Could one of you guys please post it as a answer?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace Please read above comment. Thank you.

Comment: @purple11111 done =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That CSS selector will no longer apply once `popup1` is a child of the body and no longer a child of `.wrapper`. `.wrapper #popup` says there is a descendant with id `popup1` somewhere below (not necessarily a direct child, use `>` selector for that) an element with the class `wrapper`. Once `popup1` is a direct child of body that will no longer be true.

As stated in a comment above you can remove the `wrapper` portion of the selector and it will continue to apply no matter where `popup1` is in the hierarchy.

```
#popup {
  color: #fff;
}
```

This now only applies to an element with an id of `popup1` and none of its ancestors are taken into account.

Comment: Thank you for going through the trouble. And especially for the good answer off course!

Comment: No worries! Good luck.